# Specify constant value from template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with a template argument what is an unsigned int. During implementation, I have to use the following expression a lot of time (SIZE is the template parameter):

```
(SIZE + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) / sizeof(unsigned int)
```

What is the best way to put this value to a compile time constant to avoid writing out the whole expression every time I want to use it?

p.s.: I want to use the C++03 if possible.

Comment: `AppropriateName<SIZE>::value`? That would work best if this is being used from multiple separate places.

Comment: `static const size_t value = (...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
template <unsigned SIZE>
class C
{
public:
    static const unsigned NumWords=(SIZE + sizeof(unsigned int) - 1) / 
                                   sizeof(unsigned int);
};
```

Depending on your compiler, the constant should be usable at compile time:

```
int array[C<24>::NumWords];
```

C++11 offers `constexpr` for this sort of thing, but you limited the answer to C++03.

Comment: *"Depending on your compiler, the constant should be usable at compile-time"* The problem with `static const` is that old compilers didn't implement *in class initialization*. But, as I noted, **old compilers**. Any modern compiler have implemented that, and the ***enum-hack*** (The common way to solve the problem) is not needed.